# Flexible requests to database in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I have the following problem in Rails which I am not sure how to solve. I build a  test  web application,a bulletin board with ads about real estate, like simple version of http://www.trulia.com/ and obviously users can add advertisements to the site which they can then find in their "office", and thats where the problem appears. I have  8 types of advertisements, like flats, offices, garages and etc, and so I need to be able to retrieve ads that belong to some particular user and I dont want to make sql requests to all 8 tables to show this user's advertisements, if user has , for example, just 1 ad about selling a flat.
So I need something instead of

```
@garages = Garage.where("user_id = #{current_user.id}")
@flats = Flat.where("user_id = #{current_user.id}")
@offices = Office.where("user_id = #{current_user.id}")
..... and so on
```

I have User model so all ads belong to some user and I am thinking of creating a polymorphic table which would belong to user and contained information about all ads the user invited
 it would be named, for example,"Advertisement",it would have 3 columns, user_id, advertisable_id, advertiseble_type, and it would be very easy to get all rows that belong to some particular user, but I have no idea if its possible to make Rails get ads only from those tables that are in "advertisable_type" and with those ids from "advertisable_id", I hope you understand what I mean. So, any advices for a newbie? :)

Answer (score 0):

If Your existing models Garage, Flat, Office are really advertisements, share a lot of same logic and columns, then obviously You need a data redesign.

If it's 99% the same thing why not just have `Advertisement` table and a column `advertisement_type` ? If You want a classifier for Advertisement type, simply use a separate table/model `AdvertisementTypes` and reference those by `advertisement_type_id` in Your `advertisements` table.

If You feel like there are/will be a lot of things in common, but there will be also a lots of distinct logic, it might be an ideal case for [STI (Single table inheritance)](http://blog.thirst.co/post/14885390861/rails-single-table-inheritance).
When using a STI You have different model classes which inherit from the same parent class and are stored in the same table.

```
class Advertisement < ActiveRecord::Base
  def ad_text
    "We are selling property: #{read_attribute(:ad_text)}"
  end
end

class GarageAdvertisement < Advertisement
  def ad_text
    "We are selling garage: #{read_attribute(:ad_text)}"
  end
end
```